# Test if vector field in 2D is conservative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, vector-fields

We have the vector field $F(x,y) = (\frac{-y}{x^2 + y^2} , \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2})$

I want to check if this vector field is conservative in $D =  ℝ^2 - (0,0) $.
Is it enough to check for equality between the partial derivative with respect to y for the first component and the partial derivative with respect to $x$ for the second component or does the domain pose problems for this method?

Comment: Domain is not simply connected, so it poses some problems indeed

Comment: Try computing the integral along the unit circle.

Comment: That's a great idea, thanks @amd